# Android Unit Test: How to mock Android's context

Tags: android, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I'm new to Android unit test and was wondering how I can mock the context if I want to unit test the getSomething() below.

Thanks a lot in advance!

```
public class Provider {
private final String packageName;
public Provider(Context context) {
     packageName = context.getPackageName();
}


public Data getSomething() {
    return get(packageName);
}

private Data get(String packageName) {
 // return something here based on the packageName

}

}
```

I tried

```
@Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        provider = new Provider(mock(Context.class));
    }

    @Test
    public void DoSomethingTest() {
        final Data data = provider.getSomething();
        assertThat(data).isNotNull();
    }
```

But I got the error below: 
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
        at android.content.Context.(Context.java:4)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.(ContextWrapper.java:5)

Comment: This is not a UI unit test but a functional test

Answer (score 2):

You call `getPackageName();` on the `Context`-mock. To get this running you have to mock the method like:

```
Mockito.when(mock.getPackageName()).thenReturn("myPackage");
```

But this makes your test pretty much useless. But thinking about this, this isn't a test which I would write because (assuming it works as you expecting it) it just tests the framework method `getPackageName()`. In your tests you should test YOUR code or to be more specific your algorithms and not the successful call of methods.